# htaccess Challenge: rewrite perfection for secure website structure

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I am working on a new project where I want to improve the security by using 2 level folders.
The folder "Core" contains all the folders including the "public" which needs to be the only folder the visitor can access.

A short introduction about my webdir:

```
webdir
 | - .htaccess (core)
 | - classes
 | - functions
 | - public
      | - .htaccess (public)
      | - css
      | - files
          | - de
          | - en
          | - general
          | - nl
      | - images
      | - index.php
      | - js
      | - swf            
 | - template
```

**For your information:**

- My public/index.php file sorts out in which section the files are located via [geturl] and [section]. The request "http://example.com/nl/openfile" points to:

  > public/index.php
- this file reads the $_GET and sees that [geturl] is "openfile" in the [section] "nl"

  > public/index.php wants to open: "files/nl/openfile.php"
- this is how it works and I want it to work!

What I want to achieve with my .htaccess is the following:

- The website supports 3 languages: en/de/nl. When no language is set then the nl language should be default.
- http://example.com/nl/contact needs to target the file: public/files/nl/contact.php
- Currently, when the visitor inputs http://example.com/nl/css (with no trailing slash, the problem doesn't occur when the trailing slash is added) the server translates this to http://example.com/public/css/?section=nl. 
  This is too much information for the visitor. I don't want users to see where the files are located.
- The public folder should not be accessed directly. So when a users inputs http://example.com/public this should be redirected to http://example.com/nl/

My current .htaccess files:

> **.htaccess (core)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customer.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.customer.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^company(.*)$ public/$1?section=company [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule !(nl|en|de)/(.*).*  /webdir/nl/ [R=301,L]           # IF NO LANG ISSET THAN NL REDIRECT
RewriteRule ^error(.*).*        public/?getpage=error&%1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(nl|en|de)/(.*).*  public/$2?section=$1&%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> **.htaccess (public)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*).* index.php?geturl=$1&%1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve the .htaccess files?

Summarized, I want the .htaccess to do the following:

- The website supports 3 languages: en/de/nl. When no language is set then the nl language should be default.
- http://example.com/nl/contact needs to target the file: public/files/nl/contact.php
- Currently, when the visitor inputs http://example.com/nl/css (with no trailing slash, the problem doesn't occur when the trailing slash is added) the server translates this to http://example.com/public/css/?section=nl. 
  This is too much information for the visitor. I don't want users to see where the files are located.
- The public folder should not be accessed directly. So when a users inputs http://example.com/public this should be redirected to http://example.com/nl/

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can block an entire directory by putting an `.htaccess` with `deny from all` inside?

This way you can keep your project structure simpler and more portable.

Comment: I know that's possible but when I do so I can't access any files in that folder. Also when I put a deny from all in the public folder the website can't be accessed.

Comment: of course you don't put that in public folder, just in your classes dir

Comment: Okay, now I understand where you're going. Thank you for your answer but it doesn't solve the problem I described above..